# PHP Error al insertar datos MYSQL

Tags: php, mysqli, mariadb

Buenas, estoy intentando insertar datos a mis tablas mysql, pero tengo problemas para insertarlo.

Resulta que quiero insertar mis datos en estas dos tablas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo de mi formulario **mantenimiento_empleado.php**:

```
<form action="php/registrar_empleado.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

              <div class="row">

                <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                  <label for="idnombre">Nombre:</label>
                  <input type="text" REQUIRED class="form-control" id="idnombre" name="txtnombre" placeholder="Ingresar Nombre">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group col-sm-8">
                  <label for="idapellido">Apellidos:</label>
                  <input type="text" REQUIRED class="form-control" id="idapellido" name="txtapellidos"  placeholder="Ingresar Apellidos">
                </div>

              </div>


              <div class="row">

                <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
                  <label for="iddni">DNI:</label>
                  <input type="text" REQUIRED class="form-control" id="iddni"  name="txtdni"  placeholder="Ingresar DNI">
                </div>


                <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
                  <label for="idcelular">Telf/Cel:</label>
                  <input type="text" REQUIRED class="form-control" id="idcelular" name="txtcelular" placeholder="Ingresar Telf/Cel">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
                  <label for="idemail">E-mail:</label>
                  <input type="email" REQUIRED class="form-control" id="idemail" name="txtemail" placeholder="Ingresar Email">
                </div>

              </div>

              <div class="row">

                <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                  <label for="idubicacion">Usuario:</label>
                  <input type="text" REQUIRED class="form-control" id="idubicacion" name="txtusuario" placeholder="Ingresar Ususario del Empleado">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                  <label for="idubicacion">Contraseña:</label>
                  <input type="text" REQUIRED class="form-control" id="idubicacion" name="txtcontraseña" placeholder="Ingresar Contraseña">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
                  <label for="sel1">Estado:</label>
                  <select class="form-control" name="txtestado" id="sel1">
                    <option value="Activo">Activo</option>
                    <option value="Inactivo">Inactivo</option>
                  </select>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
                  <label for="sel1">Tipo:</label>
                  <select class="form-control" name="txttipo" id="sel1">
                    <option value="Vendedor">Vendedor</option>
                    <option value="Almacenero">Almacenero</option>
                  </select>
                </div>

              </div>

              <div class="row">

                <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                  <label for="idubicacion">Ubicacion:</label>
                  <input type="text" REQUIRED class="form-control" name="txtubicacion" id="idubicacion" placeholder="Ingresar Ubicacion">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                  <label for="exampleInputFile">Subir Foto:</label>
                  <input type="file" name="imgempleado" id="exampleInputFile">
                </div>

              </div>

          <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Registrar</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Cancelar</button>
      </form>
```

Y este es el codigo con el cual inserto mis datos **registrar_empleado.php**:

```
<?php
require_once("conexion.php"); 

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    # code...
    $nombre=$_POST["txtnombre"];
    $apellidos=$_POST["txtapellidos"];
    $dni=$_POST["txtdni"];
    $telf=$_POST["txtcelular"];
    $email=$_POST["txtemail"];
    $usuario=$_POST["txtusuario"];
    $contraseña=$_POST["txtcontraseña"];
    $estado=$_POST["txtestado"];
    $tipo=$_POST["txttipo"];
    $ubicacion=$_POST["txtubicacion"];
    $fecha_registro = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $imagen=$_FILES['imgempleado']['name'];
    $ruta=$_FILES['imgempleado']['tmp_name'];
    $destino='fotos/'.$imagen;
    copy($ruta, $destino);



$sql = "INSERT INTO empleado ( nombre, apellidos, tipo, dni, ubicacion, telfmovil, email, imagen, fecha_registro)
VALUES ('$nombre', '$apellidos', '$tipo','$dni', '$ubicacion','$telf', '$email', '$destino','$fecha_registro')";



if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {


$sql2="INSERT INTO usuario (usuario, contraseña, estado) VALUES ( '$usuario', '$contraseña', '$estado')";

if ($conn->query($sql2)==TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
}else{
     echo "Error: " . $sql2 . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}



} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();


}


?>
```

Pero al momento de registrar los datos, me aparece el siguiente error:

```
Error: INSERT INTO usuario (usuario, contraseña, estado) VALUES ( 'admin', '123', 'Inactivo')
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '�a, estado) VALUES ( 'admin', '123', 'Inactivo')' at line 1
```

Y no se como solucionarlo. Pienso que tal vez presenta ese error por la clave foránea **id_empleado** que estoy ignorando. Y no se que hacer con ella. Así que si alguien sabe como solucionarlo, agradecería mucho la ayuda.

Comment: Si sabes que el problema está en la consulta, no hace falta que publiques todo el código: http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

el error creo que lo tienes aqui:

```
$sql2="INSERT INTO usuario (usuario, contraseña, estado) VALUES ( '$usuario', '$contraseña', '$estado')";
```

Deberias cambiar el campo contraseña por contrasena o password, la ñ es la que da el error

Comment: Y para aumentar el campo de la clave foranea(id_empleado)? Pensaba que con la primera inserción el campo foraneo se generaba automáticamente, pero en la tabla usuario, el campo se almacena con valor 0, cuando debería ser 1 del id_empleado.

Comment: Lo tienes como autoincrement?

Comment: Yo lo hago asi: `$idEmpleado = $conn->insert_id;
$sql2="INSERT INTO usuario (id_empleado, usuario, contraseña, estado) VALUES ( '$idEmpleado', '$usuario', '$contraseña', '$estado')";` haber si asi funciona

Comment: el id_empleado de la tabla empleado si.

Comment: me sirvió, mil gracias.

Comment: El campo de la clave foranea `usuario.id_empleado` no sabe hacia a donde apuntar cuando insertas en la tabla `usuario`, y no debería dejarte insertar ya que le estas indicando que `usuario` es hijo de `empleado`, y por lo tanto debe existir `empleado` para que pueda existir `usuario`, es un error de integridad referencial